# Are $X/Y$ and $Y$ independent if $f_{X|Y=y}(x)=3x^2/y^3(0<x<y)$ and $f_Y (y)=5y^4(0<y<1)$

Tags: probability

Are $X/Y$ and $Y$ independent if $f_{X|Y=y}(x)=3x^2/y^3(0<x<y)$ and $f_Y (y)=5y^4(0<y<1)$?

This is what I have so far:

> $$f_X(x)=\frac {15} 2 x^2 (1-x^2) (0<x<1)$$
>
> $$\implies \mathbb{P}(X/Y \le t | Y=y)= P(X\le ty)=\int^{ty}_{-\infty} f_X(x)dx$$

Which depends on y. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Check whether or not $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

Comment: @AlexR. Not necessary.

Comment: @Cristian I am surprised by the outcome of this page: did you read grand_chat's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition
$$
f_{X|Y=y}(x)={f_{X,Y}(x,y)\over f_Y(y)}\\
\therefore\; f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}15x^2y,&0<x<y<1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Let $Z=X/Y$.
$$
{d(z,y)\over d(x,y)}=\begin{vmatrix}{1\over y}&-{x\over y^2}\\0&1\end{vmatrix}={1\over y}\\
f_{Z,Y}(z,y)\Big{|}{d(z,y)\over d(x,y)}\Big{|}=f_{X,Y}(x,y)\\
\therefore\; f_{Z,Y}(z,y)=\begin{cases}15x^2y^2=15z^2y^4,&0<z,y<1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Now 
$$
f_Z(z)=\begin{cases}\int_{0}^115z^2y^4dy=3z^2&,0<z<1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Therefore we have
$$
f_{Z,Y}(z,y)=f_Z(z)f_Y(y)
$$
i.e. $Z,Y$ are mutually independent.

> Your mistake

$P(Y=y)=\int_y^yf_Y(u)du=0$ as $Y$ is continuous. So $P(X\le tY|Y=y)=P(X\le tY,Y=y)/P(Y=y)$ does not make sense.

For $t<1$ what you can do is
$$
P(X\le tY|0<Y<y)={P(X\le tY,0<Y<y)\over P(0<Y<y)}={\int_{0}^y\int_{-\infty}^{tu}p_{X,Y}(x,u)dxdu\over \int_0^y p_Y(u)du}\\
={\int_{0}^y\int_{0}^{tu}{15x^2u}dxdu\over \int_0^y 5u^4du}
={\int_{0}^y5(tu)^3udu\over \int_0^y 5u^4du}=t^3{\int_{0}^y5u^4du\over \int_0^y 5u^4du}=t^3
$$ 
which as expected is a function of only $t$.

Comment: How can you do it without change of variable?

Comment: @CristianDesivo I can't...:)

Comment: But if Z and Y are independent wouldn't $P(Z\le z|Y=y)$ not depend on y?

Comment: If $f_Z(z)f_Y(y)=f_{Z,Y}(z,y)=f_{Z|Y=y}(z) f_Y(y)$ then $f_Z(z)f_Y(y)=f_{Z|Y=y}(z) f_Y(y)$ so $f_Z(z)=f_{Z|Y=y}(z)$

Comment: So you've correctly concluded that if Z,Y are independent $f_{Z|Y=y}(z)$ is a function of $z$ only. In general cases it'd be a function of both z and y. I removed my previous comment. You Are you trying to show me some kind of contradiction?

Comment: I'm asking if my reasoning in that is right, because if it is I don't know why I got that they are dependent when they aren't

Comment: $P(X/Y \le t | Y = y)$ Is the probability that X/Y is less than t given that Y=y and that is $P(X/y \le t) = P(X \le yt) $ is it not?

Comment: @CristianDesivo I edited my post. Does it answer your question now?

Comment: Conditional probability for absolutely continuous random variables are not defined like that.

Comment: $f_{X|Y}(x|y)= \frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)} {f_Y (y)}$

Comment: f=density, the P we're calculating is distribution ($\neq$ density). Your relation is correct. But how do you calculate conditional distribution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you integrated $P(X<ty|Y<y)$ instead of $P(X<tY|Y<y)$

Comment: Nope want me to show the steps? Better yet, try it yourself.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that would be helpfull

Comment: @CristianDesivo Done.

Comment: It was the other equality I had a problem with, but I see it now, t is always less than 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to derive the exact density of $X/Y$. Just compute
$$
P(X/Y\le t\mid Y=y)\stackrel{(1)}=P(X\le ty\mid Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^{ty}f_{X|Y=y}(x)\,dx=\int_0^{ty}{3x^2\over y^3}\,dx=t^3
$$
and note that the answer is free of $y$, hence $X/Y$ is independent of $Y$. Your mistake was dropping the conditioning on $\{Y=y\}$ in step (1).

Comment: To sum up, using the notation $Z=X/Y$ for clarity, $$f_{Z\mid Y=y}(z)=|y|\,f_{X\mid Y=y}(yz)$$